# SQL actually executed as planned in ORACLE?

Tags: oracle, execution-plan

I wonder if SQL is definitely executed as execution plan.

I mean.. is the actual SQL execution process always consistent with execution plan, i.e. does the same SQL always give the same plan?

Comment: Hmm, two answers saying essentially the opposite!

Comment: @Colin'tHart: I think our two answers are both right from a given point of view. In the short term an plan generated now (as an estimate or when actually running the statements) is likely to be the plan followed when the statements are next run, but over the longer term plans can differ greatly. Query planning is a very complex subject. There are massive books and many research papers written on the subject at various depths if the OP wants to really dig into the area.

Comment: Yes, the question is ambiguous: it could mean 1) Does the executor do something else than what was planned? or 2) Does a subsequent execution always choose the same plan (and execution)?

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that no, the same SQL doesn't automatically lead to the same execution plan.

For example, one may have a small table and the optimizer may realise that there's no point in using an index since an FTS (Full Table Scan) would be cheaper than trawling through an index and then performing lookups.

The "No" answer is the reason that Oracle introduced Outlines to implement [Plan Stability](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25178_01/server.1111/e16638/outlines.htm). Many posts on the Oracle forums concern poor DBAs complaining about the fact that their system worked fine on Tuesday but that on Wednesday it had slowed right down. Further investigation showed that this was due to a critical change in the Execution Plan for a particular query.

What Plan Stability is basically doing is while accepting that some plans may be sub-optimal, the DBAs/Devs would prefer a stable system over one which might change catastrophically in an unpredictable fashion.

Some good information about this can be found [here](http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/outlines.php) and [here](http://blog.tanelpoder.com/oracle/performance/sql/oracle-sql-plan-stability/). The oracle-base site is one of the best sources of Oracle information and Tanel Poder is a very big hitter in the Oracle world.

Answer (score 0):

There are reasons why Oracle might change exec plan without statistics updates. There are Dynamic sampling, Bind variables peeking and Performance baselines. These features should help Oracle to adapt the execution plan with actual load and actual data characteristics.

There can be various reasons why Oracle decides to use different exec plan to the same SQL. The most common are:

- different optimizer goal
- different bind/define datatype
- different NLS_PARAMETERS of client (NLS_SORT, NLS_COMP)

There are also other more curious like different version of client lib(OCI/JDBC/native PL/SQL), different size of receiving buffer on client, ...
For more information look the the view [V$SQL_SHARED_CURSOR.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/dynviews_2124.htm#REFRN30254)

When the query is running there is exact mapping between exec. plan and stacktrace of the Oracle binary. When you execute pstack on session process and you will see that there are several functions starting their name with `knl` the you know that exec. plan consists of nested loops (k-kernel, nl-nested loop, hs/hj - hash join). I think a long time age Oracle even released some documentation explaining how to decipher function names in their binaries. If you like a theory, then: PL/SQL is compiled into the bytecode called m-code/p-code(adopted from programing lang. ADA) and this bytecode runs on a virtual machine. While for SQL execution Oracle uses AST (Abstract syntax tree). Each node in exec plan represents one node in AST and each node is evaluated by one C-function. (Other databases like MySQL and PostreSQL do it the same way).

Answer (score -1):

Basically, yes in the short term. If it were intending to go a different way it would generate a different plan, and no database (to my knowledge) backtracks and finds a different plan once it has started processing.

If you are looking at a plan generated before a query was run then any statistics (rows, number of iterations of lopped constructs, and so forth) will be estimates, so these are likely to differ from what exactly happens during execution. This is because it would be to time and IO expensive to scan/analyse everything in exquisite depth in order to make the stats exact before actually running the query, and this is why query engines sometimes get things wrong and take a less than optimal path (needing index hints and such to encourage/force them in a better direction) - the analysis required (and/or stats that would need to be stored) to always get the most efficient solution would be impossibly expensive in the general case.

There is one huge caveat when considering the longer term though: a plan generated now may differ from a plan generated for the same query later today, even without structural changes (changes to indexes and such) because changes in data update the recorded statistics so may alter what the planner sees as the best way to go. It is even possible for the plan to change from one instant to the next (such as between you getting the actual plan for the last query asking for it to be executed again) but this is much rarer as the more intelligent database engines (Postgres, MS SQL Server, Oracle, ...) cache generated plans to reduce repeated analysis.

If you explicitly tell the engine not to cache a plan (or it decides not to for some reason) then the plan used could potentially change between you asking for an estimated plan and actually running a query. It could also change between you getting an actual plan output from one instance of running the query and running the same thing again, but again this is unlikely as the stats used to decide the plan are unlikely to have changed significantly.

Pinch of salt time: most of my in-depth experience is with MS SQL Server, so there may be details in other engines I am inaccurate on.

Comment: Wrong: Oracle *can* and *does* change execution plan once starting execution in certain cases.

Comment: @Colin'tHart - could you explain this? I thought that the OP meant that the same SQL should always produce the same plan - what exactly do you mean about changing during execution?

Comment: @Colin'tHart: could you point to documentation about that? I would be most impressed if it has the intelligence to usefully do when I now have in my head that you mean, and would love to read into the details of how it is achieved.

Comment: I have it at home in a folder from a course given by Jonathan Lewis. I'll try to dig it out.

Comment: I was going to suggest my favourite bed-time reading to the OP - Jonathan Lewis' [Cost-based Oracle Fundamentals](http://www.amazon.com/Cost-Based-Oracle-Fundamentals-Experts-Voice/dp/1590596366/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1432284274&sr=8-2&keywords=jonathan+lewis) - a mighty tome of ~650 pages on the basics of the Oracle optimiser.

Comment: Broadly speaking this answer is correct, but each DBMS has salient differences to beware of.

Comment: @Vérace Adaptive Joins in 12c is one example, but I believe some other changes could be made on the fly in older versions too. https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/entry/what_s_new_in_12c

Comment: After my time - I haven't used Oracle for a while now. Must get my nose back in some more of that light bed-time reading! :-)

Comment: Same here. Personally I don't like the direction Oracle is going: adding layer upon layer of complexity to mask or try to fix fundamental design flaws. Moving to PostgreSQL has been a revelation for me.

Comment: Couldn't agree more - I really like PostgreSQL, but unfortunately MySQL is more popular in my field (molecular biology/bioinformatics).